# Разобрать файл на чанки и собрать обратно в js

Tags: javascript

Я использую высокоуровневое API для разделение файла на чанки. `File.slice(start, end)` После чего добавляю эти части в масив и после пытаюсь собрать обратно в файл и получить url  для воспроизведения. Итог: Файл ломаеться и не могу воспроизвести его. Код ниже

```
 const file = ...videoFile
 const chunkSize = 1048576 * 30
 let chunkStart = 0
 let chunkEnd = chunkSize
 let totalCount = 1
 let count = 0
 let blobArray = []

 const nextChunk = () => {
  if(count <= totalCont) {
   const chunk = file.slice(chunkStart, chunkEnd, file.type)
   blobArray = [...blobArray, chunk]
   count++
   chunkStart = chunkEnd
   chunkEnd = chunkEnd + chunkSize >= file.size ? file.size : chunkEnd + chunkSize
   nextChunk()
  } else {
   const newFile = new File(blobArray, 'video.mp4')
   const r = new FileReader()
   r.onload = (event) => {
     console.log(event.target.result)
   }
   r.readAsDataURL(newFile)
  }
 }
```

Возможно проблема в том что строка начинаеться с `data:application/octet-stream` если я правильно помню то это значит что это часть файла. Если подскажите как исправить, буду благодарен.
Ожидаемый результат. Способ разделять файл разделять на части а потом соберать его обратно без потери целосности что бы в последствии можно было бы передавать эти части на бек.

Comment: Зачем разбивать файл на чанки если в любом случае большой файл будет передан на сервер потоком?

Comment: Возможно я не правильно понял ваш вопрос. Но именно с этим я и пытаюсь бороться. У меня нет доступа к серверу, но я знаю что там multer - s3. Нужен способ передавать файл по частям на сервер. Для этого я использовал slice. Но этот бло не может собраться на той стороне

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кому интересно, конкретную проблему с тем что невозможно вернуть файл в изначальное состояние на фронте я решил таким образом.

```
const chunks = [Blob созданые через slice]
const src = URL.createObjectURL(new File(chunks, 'video.mp4'))
```

Но проблема передачи этих самых блобов на сервер осталась. Если у вас есть идеи прошу в другой топик
[Blob полученый при slice файла на добавляется в FormData](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1203685/blob-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-slice-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-formdata)