# Blob полученый при slice файла на добавляется в FormData

Tags: javascript, fileupload

Я использую стандартное апи `File.slice(start, end)` что бы получить часть файла и отправить его на сервер. Но при попытке добавить получившийся blob в FormData в нетворке его нет и при консоль логе тоже пусто. Только если истользовать `FormData.get('propertyName')` я могу увидеть блоб. С чем это может быть связано и как отразиться на передаче файла на сервер